# Border around an applet

Tags: java, applet

Are there any methods to have a border around an applet such that all components are enclosed within a border?

```
            this.getContentPane().setBorder()
```

method is not present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using JLabel on the Form design and set the border using properties

Answer (score 3):

You can either:

- define a border in **CSS** for the `<applet>` element, or
- create a **root container** (`JPanel`) within your applet, and give that the border (`setBorder`).

*Explaination of root container (see question in comment below):*

Usually, you add the UI elements directly to the JApplet (or JFrame, JDialog):

```
setLayout(new FlowLayout());
add(new JLabel("Name: "));
add(new JTextField(20));
```

But you can also create your own root container (as an intermediate container):

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
JPanel root = new JPanel();
add(root, BorderLayout.CENTER);
root.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

root.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
root.add(new JLabel("Name: "));
root.add(new JTextField(20));
```

Comment: Root container? Can you please tell me how to do that. Thanks